# Cant boot ubuntu in vmware after moving files from C to D partition (cant exit from emergency mode)

Tags: boot, virtualization, vmware

Here are the screenshots of what I am getting

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s08H3.png)

[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX10c.png)

[third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqCvK.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.